# How to setup a development environment on single computer using visual studio and active directory

Tags: visual-studio-2015, active-directory, development-environment

We have been developing a web site for a client in visual studio; so far we have the basic design and database working and are fairly comfortable with the environment we've setup.

Now we need to start working with active directory. I have a desktop and a laptop that I would like to be able to develop on; currently we just transfer the solution and database to one or the other when we are ready to code there.

The specific task at hand is to start assigning ACLs to a new folder we have created when the user clients "new project"; and also to create automatic authentication so that the user is automatically logged in to the website when they log into the computer and access the website; i.e. no logon page in my website.

But this question isn't related necessarily to how to do that, it's really asking how do I set up a local environment to develop on. We've setup an AD VM and a few AD clients and have spent a good amount of time getting them access to the internet by bridging the connection to my real physical adapter.

The problem is that we need a domain to make this work and that ends up messing up the bridged internet connections.

Visual studio seems to provide local development resources for SQL server and IIS so the user can start to code using those systems on a local visual studio instance alone; Is there something similar for active directory and how do I set it up? If not, what's the best way to go about setting up the development environment for this?